# How to check if the checkbox is checked or not in protractor using javascript

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to write an end to end protractor test and I am stuck with checking if the checkbox is enabled or not since it does not have the checked property or anything. 
Is there any way in javascript we could check from a list by getting an element and check if it is checked and if it is checked get the text for that.

This is what i have for the HTML:

```html
<li>

<div _ngcontent-c8="" class="ng-tns-c8-2" >

<input _ngcontent-c8="" class="ng-tns-c8-2" type="checkbox" id="Team TableAccepted">

<label _ngcontent-c8="" class="ng-tns-c8-2" for="Team TableAccepted">Accepted</label></div>

</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isSelected()` should do the trick here:

Given this input: `<input type="checkbox" id="team" />`

To check if it's selected, we would write the following:

```
const checkbox = element(by.id('team'));

expect(checkbox.isSelected()).toBe(true);
```

If you do not want to use protractor and would prefer vanilla js, this is another option:

`const isChecked = document.getElementById('team').checked;`

Also, neither HTML4 nor HTML5 allows space characters in `id` attribute values. In the case of your input: `<input _ngcontent-c8="" class="ng-tns-c8-2" type="checkbox" id="Team TableAccepted">`, `id="Team TableAccepted` is not valid HTML. For `id` attributes, limit the value to one descriptor.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the checkbox is selected/not in two ways

1. Through the command isSelected()
2. Through attribute aria-checked=true/false(For mat componenets)